# Why my subdirectory "/game" of the react website cannot be served from nginx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I have a website with has one subdirectory named "/game". There is no problem when I click the tab in navbar when I execute the website in localhost (localhost:3000/game is working!). But when I want to access using my domain address, it gives me error "404
The requested page was not found." (mydomain/game is not working!)

What am I missing?

**React Part - Navbar.js :**

```
...

<a href="/game">
  <span>Game</span>
</a>

...
```

**React Part - Game.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Game extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='text-white text-center game'>
                GAME INFORMATION
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**React Part - App.js :**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
          <div className="App">
            <header className='Main-header'>
              <Navbar />
              <Hero />
            </header>
            <About />
            <Gallery />
            <Faq />
          </div>
        } />
        <Route path="/game" element={<Game />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Nginx Part,
after typing *vi default* :**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably just an ssl error. Try to get a certificate from letsencrypt.